# How to connect three tables with one-many relationship in gorm

Tags: rest, go, backend, go-gorm

I am learning the go and gorm for my project and I am having an issue with a database structure. I want to connect three tables with one to many relationship using gorm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uoFf.png)

```
├── main.go
├── db
│   └── db.go
├── models
│   ├── application.go
│   ├── schedule.go
│   └── stream.go
└── handlers
    └── application_handler.go
```

This is my folder structure for the project

#### main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/nabilpatel4012/go-backend/db"
    "github.com/nabilpatel4012/go-backend/handlers"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize the database
    db.InitDB()

    // Initialize the Gin router
    r := gin.Default()

    // Application handlers
    r.GET("/applications/:id", handlers.GetApplicationByID)
    r.POST("/applications", handlers.CreateApplication)

    // Run the server
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

#### db/db.go

```
package db

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nabilpatel4012/go-backend/models"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var (
    DB  *gorm.DB
    err error
)

func InitDB() {
    // Update your MySQL database credentials here
    dsn := "username:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/mydb?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"

    DB, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database" + err.Error())
    }

    // Migrate the tables
    DB.AutoMigrate(&models.Application{}, &models.Stream{}, &models.Schedule{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to migrate tables: " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Database connected and tables migrated successfully!")
}
```

#### handlers/handlers.go

```
package handlers

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/nabilpatel4012/go-backend/db"
    "github.com/nabilpatel4012/go-backend/models"
)

// GetApplicationByID handles the GET request to retrieve an application by ID.
func GetApplicationByID(c *gin.Context) {
    // Parse the application ID from the URL parameter
    id := c.Param("id")

    // Fetch the application from the database
    var application models.Application
    if err := db.DB.Preload("Streams.Schedule").First(&application, id).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": "Application not found"})
        return
    }

    // Respond with the application data
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, application)
}

// POST CreateApplication handles the POST request to add an application.
func CreateApplication(c *gin.Context) {
    var newApplication models.Application

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&newApplication); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Invalid request body"})
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, newApplication)

    if err := db.DB.Create(&newApplication).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Failed to create application"})
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, newApplication)
}
```

#### models/application.go

```
package models

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Application struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID                uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ApplicationName   string
    ApplicationSlogan string
    Streams           []Stream `gorm:"foreignKey:ApplicationID"` // One-to-Many relationship with streams
}
```

#### models/stream.go

```
package models

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Stream struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID                uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ApplicationID     uint // Foreign key for the Application
    StreamTitle       string
    StreamLink        string
    StreamThumbnail   string
    StreamDescription string
    Schedule          []Schedule // One-to-Many relationship with schedule
}
```

#### models/schedule.go

```
package models

import (
    "time"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Schedule struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID         uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    StreamID   uint // Foreign key for the Stream
    StartDate  string
    EndDate    string
    Days       string
    StartTime  string
    EndTime    string
    CreatedBy  string
    CreatedOn  time.Time
    ModifiedBy string
    ModifiedOn time.Time
}
```

In this code I am having error with the table structure.
On GET Request it is giving me this response

```
{
    "error": "Application not found"
}
```

On POST Request it is giving me this response

```
{
    "error": "Invalid request body"
}
```

for reference this is the JSON I am sending as a request

```
{
  "ApplicationName": "Sample App",
  "ApplicationSlogan": "A simple app for testing",
  "Streams": [
    {
      "StreamTitle": "Stream 1",
      "StreamLink": "https://example.com/stream1",
      "StreamThumbnail": "https://example.com/thumbnail1.jpg",
      "StreamDescription": "This is Stream 1 description",
      "Schedule": [
        {
          "StartDate": "2023-08-01",
          "EndDate": "2023-08-31",
          "Days": "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri",
          "StartTime": "09:00:00",
          "EndTime": "11:00:00",
          "CreatedBy": "John Doe",
          "CreatedOn": "2023-07-31 10:00:00",
          "ModifiedBy": "xys",
          "ModifiedOn":"2023-07-31 10:00:00"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StreamTitle": "Stream 2",
      "StreamLink": "https://example.com/stream2",
      "StreamThumbnail": "https://example.com/thumbnail2.jpg",
      "StreamDescription": "This is Stream 2 description",
      "Schedule": [
        {
          "StartDate": "2023-08-02",
          "EndDate": "2023-08-30",
          "Days": "Tue,Thu,Sat",
          "StartTime": "15:00:00",
          "EndTime": "17:00:00",
          "CreatedBy": "Jane Smith",
          "CreatedOn": "2023-07-31 12:00:00",
          "ModifiedBy": "xyz",
          "ModifiedOn":"2023-07-31 10:00:00"
          
        },
        {
          "StartDate": "2023-08-02",
          "EndDate": "2023-08-30",
          "Days": "Tue,Thu,Sat",
          "StartTime": "15:00:00",
          "EndTime": "17:00:00",
          "CreatedBy": "Jane Smith",
          "CreatedOn": "2023-07-31 12:00:00",
          "ModifiedBy": "xyz",
          "ModifiedOn":"2023-07-31 10:00:00"
          
        },
        {
          "StartDate": "2023-08-01",
          "EndDate": "2023-08-31",
          "Days": "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri",
          "StartTime": "09:00:00",
          "EndTime": "11:00:00",
          "CreatedBy": "John Doe",
          "CreatedOn": "2023-07-31 10:00:00",
          "ModifiedBy": "xyz",
          "ModifiedOn":"2023-07-31 10:00:00"
        }
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can use nested struct model, and join(query) in gorm. https://gist.github.com/wangrenjun/48f03d2980c8f953f1e9ca5d7e09de5c

Comment: Thanks For Helping me I'll try to implement this solution